# How to edit a YAML file in python repeatedly using a variable without defining a specific value for the key?

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml, ruamel.yaml

This is my example YAML file,

```
# Employee records
Developer:
  Department: IT
  Manager: ABCD
  Floor: 2nd
  Lab: 4
Support:
  Department: General
  Manager: XYZ
  Floor: 1st
  Lab: 1
Martin:
  name: Martin Devloper
  job: Developer
  skills:
    - python
```

I want to read this yaml file from a particular directory, edit it and then save the edited text on the same yaml file. I got this code from a link somewhere as follows:

```
import sys
from ruamel.yaml import YAML
inp_fo = open("C:/<Users>/Master 
1TB/source/repos/New_insertdata/PythonApplication3/inp.yaml").read() 
#Read the YAML File

yaml = YAML()
code = yaml.load(inp_fo)
sys.stdout.write('\n')
code.insert(1, 'sensor', 'None', comment="new key")
inp_fo2 = open("inp.yaml","w") #Open the file for Write
yaml.dump(code, inp_fo2) ##Write to file with new parameter
inp_fo2.close() ## close the file
```

When I execute it I get output as follows:

```
# Employee records
Developer:
  Department: IT
  Manager: ABCD
  Floor: 2nd
  Lab: 4
Support:
  Department: General
  Manager: XYZ
  Floor: 1st
  Lab: 1
Martin:
  name: Martin 
  job: Developer
  skills:
    - python
Tabitha: None
```

But instead I need:

```
# Employee records
Developer:
  Department: IT
  Manager: ABCD
  Floor: 2nd
  Lab: 4
Support:
  Department: General
  Manager: XYZ
  Floor: 1st
  Lab: 1
Martin:
  name: Martin 
  job: Developer
  skills:
    - python
Tabitha:
  name: Tabitha Bitumen
  job: Developer
  skills:
    - Java
```

How to code this?

I entered value for 'Tabitha' as None because code.insert was not getting executed if I don't insert a value for it.

Now, I want to edit this yaml file repeatedly so I want to define a variable for each key value, so everytime once the variable value changes the code will be executed and new key values will be inserted in the existing yaml file. I don't want to delete the earlier contents of YAML file just need to go on adding new contents (key & value) (content will be employee details like name, job, skills).

I am completely new to this coding language so if I am wrong please correct me. Also can anyone explain me what is the use of indent, sequence & mapping in ruamel.yaml and how can I use them in code?

I am a learner and the above example is a random yaml file just an example to learn ruamel.yaml.

Let me explain you what I want exactly,
The following content will remain static.

```
 # Employee records
Developer:
  Department: IT
  Manager: ABCD
  Floor: 2nd
  Lab: 4
Support:
  Department: General
  Manager: XYZ
  Floor: 1st
  Lab: 1
```

But the key values (employee details) are going to change. Example I want:
    Martin:
      name: Martin Devloper
      job: Developer
      skills:
        - python

```
"Martin" should be a "variableP"
name: "variableQ"
job: "variableR"
skills:
  - "variableS"
```

similarly if another employee adds his details the code will automatically add another employee details in those variables.
because according to your code, I will have to repeatedly add

```
code['Tabitha'] = dict(name='Tabitha Bitumen', job='Developer', skills=['Java'])
```

again and again for other employee data which I don't want, I just want a code where I could define a variable whose value will keep on changing and will edit the same yaml file repeatedly and do not delete the earlier employee details.
There is no limit for list of employees to be get added so I don't want to edit the code again and again.

I basically know C and arduino programming language so looking for a way to define variables in a code which will make my work easy.

Comment: Worth pointing out that you're essentially using this YAML file as a crappy database. Unless you really care about having life updates on a human readable text file at all times, you should probably look into something like sqlite instead which is built for this sort of usage.

Comment: Please explain **in detail** where the values for your variables come from (from another YAML file? From user input? ,etc).

Comment: Yes the values for the variable will come from user input basically from a local website.

Comment: What is the file format that the local website writes? YAML files? What is the exact format of what you get from the website? I hope you are not trying to make your python the back-end (without experienced help).

Comment: I will be getting data in Jason format from the website, I guess is that what you are asking? Then I want to read that Jason data and add it to the variable in this code. Yes the python code will be running in back-end.

Comment: I am a student and I have no experience, so if my above idea sounds irrelevant to you please correct me!

Answer (score 3):

The YAML library you're using converts between YAML formatting and Python dictionaries. Therefore you could simple edit the dictionary to add or change a value in the YAML file. For example:

```
import sys
from ruamel.yaml import YAML
filename = "C:/<Users>/Master/1TB/source/repos/New_insertdata/PythonApplication3/inp.yaml"

yaml = YAML()
with open(filename) as inp_fo:
    code = yaml.load(inp_fo)

    code["Tabitha"] = {
                        "name":"Tabitha Bitman",
                        "job":"Developer",
                        "skills":["Python"]
                      }

with open(filename, "w") as file:
    yaml.dump(code, file) ##Write to file with new parameter
```

> There is no need to close the files as they were opened in "with"
>   statements

This will update Tabitha's details in the YAML file, assuming that the rest of your code is correct.

You can also parse a variable into the key:value lookup, replacing `code["Tabitha"]` with `code[variable_name]`.

If you are working with YAML (or JSON) files I also highly recommend looking into and understanding dictionaries in Python.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for he answer but my Key value will be changing every time and the yaml file will be edited every time when my key value changes. So can I insert a variable for the key value?
Fore example( job{key}: Developer{value}), over here my value Developer will be changing depending upon the employee so It can be "support" as well instead of "Developer".
The reason for using a variable is that I will not need to change the code again and again depending on the value.

Comment: @MEHULSOLANKI Yes you can! Simply replace `code["Tabitha"]` with `code[variable]`, although the variable must be a string.

Comment: @moralous There is no need for that to be a string. Python restricts keys to any immutable type, not just strings. E.g. `ruamel.yaml` can dump dicts that have tuples as key (and it loads them as well).

Answer (score 1):

The following assumes you are using Python3 (and you should if you are
learning Python), because it uses `pathlib` that is in the standard
library for Python3. There is a
[`pathlib2`](https://pypi.org/project/pathlib2/) package that provides that
functionality for Python2.

The example code that you present does a few strange things:

- it is not necessary to read in the content of a file
  (`open(...).read()`) and then hand that to the `.load()` method, you
  can directly pass in the file pointer (i.e. the result from just
  doing `open()`, or you can use the `Path` object and hand this to
  `.load()` without even opening the file (as shown below).
- it is unclear why a newline is written to `sys.stdout`, that really
  has no function in this snippet
- the call `code.insert(1, 'sensor', 'None', comment="new key")` does put 'sensor' as 
  a new key, **in position 1** of the dictionary like object `code`, with the value `None` 
  and the end-of-line comment "new key". (Position counting starts at 0.

If you had really ran that code you would get as output:

```
# Employee records
Developer:
  Department: IT
  Manager: ABCD
  Floor: 2nd
  Lab: 4
sensor: None  # new key
Support:
  Department: General
  Manager: XYZ
  Floor: 1st
  Lab: 1
Martin:
  name: Martin Devloper
  job: Developer
  skills:
  - python
```

At the root of your input file is a mapping with keys `Developer`,
`Support` and `Martin`. The values associate with a key can again be a
mapping (as is the case for all your root-level keys), but they can
also be a sequence (as is the value for `skills`, indicated by dash
(`-`) or scalar values (string, number, etc). The root of a YAML
document can be a scalar (which is then the only object in the
document), or a sequence. And a sequence has elements that can be
scalars (as your final line `python`), but those elements can also be
mappings or other sequences.

Mappings are loaded as Python `dict`s, sequences are loaded as Python
`list`s. In order to preserve comments (and other information),
`ruamel.yaml` will create dict- resp. list-like objects when used as
in the example. You would not be able to call `code.insert()` on a regular
Python `dict` but you can do so on what you got back (from `YAML().load()`)

If you just want to add a key-value pair at the end of a dict, you don't need to
use `.insert`, you can just do:

```
code['Tabitha'] = dict(name='Tabitha Bitumen', job='Developer', skills=['Java'])
```

If you need to move something to the end of the YAML file, you actually cannot
just update the value using e.g.

```
code['Support'] = dict(Department='General', Manager='KLM', Floor='1st', Lab=1)
```

this will get you the key/value in the old position. You would have to do

```
del code['Support']
```

first to make it forget this old position.

---

As indicated `ruamel.yaml` supports multiple ways on how to read and
write to a file. The `with` statement as `Moralous` answer introduced
is already better than explicit opening, reading and closing. You can also use
`pathlib.Path` like objects with the `.load()` and `.dump()` methods:

```
from pathlib import Path
from ruamel.yaml import YAML

path = Path('inp.yaml')  # I shortened this a bit, as I don't have a C: drive
opath = Path('outp.yaml')

yaml = YAML()
code = yaml.load(path)
code['Tabitha'] = dict(name='Tabitha Bitumen', job='Developer', skills=['Java'])
yaml.dump(code, opath)
```

which gives:

```
# Employee records
Developer:
  Department: IT
  Manager: ABCD
  Floor: 2nd
  Lab: 4
Support:
  Department: General
  Manager: XYZ
  Floor: 1st
  Lab: 1
Martin:
  name: Martin Devloper
  job: Developer
  skills:
  - python
Tabitha:
  name: Tabitha Bitumen
  job: Developer
  skills:
  - Java
```

This is almost what you want, but the default indentation of the YAML output
is 2 positions for both the dict (as you want it to be) and for the
sequence (it is counted to the beginning of your element, not to the
dash).

To get what you want, you need to specify an indent of four for the sequence, and
an offset of two for the dash withing those for spaces. You can do so by inserting,
after the `yaml = YAML()` line, a line with:

```
yaml.indent(sequence=4, offset=2)
```

---

You can also use your `YAML` instance itself in a `with` statement:

```
import sys
from pathlib import Path
from ruamel.yaml import YAML

path = Path('inp.yaml')  # I shortened this a bit, as I don't have a C: drive
opath = Path('outp.yaml')

with YAML(output=opath) as yaml:
    yaml.indent(sequence=4, offset=2)
    code = yaml.load(path)
    code['Tabitha'] = dict(name='Tabitha Bitumen', job='Developer', skills=['Java'])
    yaml.dump(code)
```

That will also give you exactly you want:

```
# Employee records
Developer:
  Department: IT
  Manager: ABCD
  Floor: 2nd
  Lab: 4
Support:
  Department: General
  Manager: XYZ
  Floor: 1st
  Lab: 1
Martin:
  name: Martin Devloper
  job: Developer
  skills:
    - python
Tabitha:
  name: Tabitha Bitumen
  job: Developer
  skills:
    - Java
```

You tagged your question with PyYAML as well. Please note that with that package
you cannot do the above: your comments in the YAML file will be lost, and 
you don't have the kind of fine control over indentation to get the result you
wanted.

Comment: Hey sorry for the wrong code, actually I have multiples yaml files in my PC so I was testing with another yaml file which has electronic components name that is why you saw name name "sensor". before posting I didn't noticed it. My bad!

Comment: I tried running your code but its giving me error "Message=TypeError("'NoneType' object does not support item assignment",)
  Source=c:\users\master 1tb\source\repos\test_proj\pythonapplication3\pythonapplication3.py
  StackTrace:
  File "c:\users\master 1tb\source\repos\test_proj\pythonapplication3\pythonapplication3.py", line 12, in <module>
    yaml.dump(code)".

You can also view the screenshot link: (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BpXUytPF61My3R0FgyB3MUgKIMI6MVSS/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Check your YAML file ( `inp.yaml` ) it is probably empty. If you load an empty file then `code` will be `None`.

Answer (score 1):

While working on this YAML i found the question and thought to share the explanation if this could helps other in understanding in a better way.
YAML are the configuration files and we can parse JSON format using a YAML parser in python.
We can use ruamel.yaml PYPI module for building the parser in python.

### pip install ruamel.yaml

Here is the sample YAML config.yaml file:-

```
# Employee records
Developer:
  Department: IT
  Manager: ABCD
  Floor: 2nd
  Lab: 4
Support:
  Department: General
  Manager: XYZ
  Floor: 1st
  Lab: 1
Martin:
  name: Martin Devloper
  job: Developer
  skills:
    - python
Kavya:
  name: Kavya Agarwal
  job: Developer
  skills:
    - Java
Atharv:
  Name: 190.22.45.33
  Job: Smriti
  Skills:
    - python
```

Here i am attaching the YAML parser code:-

```
from ruamel.yaml import YAML
filepath = 'config.yaml'
def yaml_loader(file_path):
    yaml = YAML()
    with open(file_path) as fp:
       yaml.indent(sequence=4, offset=2)
       data = yaml.load(fp)
       data['Atharv'] = {
                       "Name":"190.22.45.33",
                       "Job":"Smriti",
                       "Skills":["python"]
                     }
    with open(file_path, "w") as file:
       yaml.dump(data, file)

yaml_loader("config.yaml")
```

---